# How can I follow a link that contains 2 things using Mechanize in Perl?

Tags: perl, hyperlink, mechanize, www-mechanize

I want to follow a link that contains $foo AND $bar.

I've tried this and it didn't work.

`$mech->follow_link( url_regex => qr/$foo/i && url_regex => qr/$bar/i)`

Answer (score 2):

You could write a regex that matches both subpatterns:

```
qr/(?=.*?$foo)(?=.*$bar)/is
```

This uses two lookaheads that can match anywhere in the string, due to the `.*` prefix.

Note that this is more inefficient, and that the matched substring will differ.

Comment: On the website i'm working on there will only be 1 link that contains both $foo and $bar in that order but there are other links that contain either $foo or $bar. Will this select that specific link?

Comment: If it will always be in the same order (`$foo` early in the string, `$bar` later), you can just use `qr/$foo.*$bar/i` and save a lot of effort.

Comment: @Robert What AKHolland said. My regex ANDs the two subregexes together (it matches if both parts match). If only one part has to match, simply use an alternation: `qr/$foo|bar/`.